# Как исправить ошибку в джанго?

Tags: python, django

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Вопрос")
    tests = models.ForeignKey("Test",on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Тест")
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вопрос'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вопросы'
        db_table_comment = "Таблица с вопросами"
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
    
    class Ans_Que(models.Model):
        answer = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Ответ")
        isRight = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Правильность")
        questions = models.ForeignKey("Question",on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Вопрос")
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ответ на вопрос'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ответы на вопросы'
        db_table_comment = "Таблица с ответами на вопросы"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer
```

У меня есть такая модель. При попытке зайти в таблицу Ans_Que выходит ошибка. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему нет столбца? Он же на самом деле есть и прописан в модели.

Comment: Так может там его и правда нет?

Comment: Что-то я не вижу нигде в коде `questions_id`

Comment: миграции применить надо